# Calling C Executable using PHP

Tags: php, html, c

I have a c file I've compiled with a executable called "run"
And want to run it with a argv[1] of testfile.txt that is in the uploads directory.

This here seems to work, but I don't understand why.

```
exec(__DIR__ . '/run uploads/testfile.txt',$output);
```

C programs are run as such:

```
./run uploads/testfile.txt
```

Adding a dot to the beginning of the exec() command makes it not work, but I'm running an executable, not a file (not a file run), why does the first example work but the other doesn't?

This doesn't work but it should?

```
exec(__DIR__ . './run uploads/testfile.txt',$output);
```

Where `./run` is the c executable, and `argv[1]` is in the uploads directory which is `testfile.txt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need the `.` when you're running a program without providing a pathname. If the program name doesn't contain `/`, the shell searches for the program in `$PATH`. By typing `./run`, it tells it to look in the current directory rather than searching for it.

Since you're providing a full path to the program by prepending `__DIR__`, it won't search for the program. It's not necessary to insert `.` before the program name in this case, and it's resulting in an incorrect filename. It's adding `.` to the last directory in `__DIR__`, and that directory doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose `__DIR__=='/foo/bar'`.

Then, `__DIR__ . './run'` would evaluate to `/foo/bar./run` which does not exist.

Comment: So how would I fix it using the dot?

Comment: @oekroek Leave out the dot, it's not needed.

Answer (score 0):

The dot concatenates two strings.
__DIR__ is a magic constant which is your php file directory not slash-terminated (see php doc).
Suppose __DIR__ = `my_dir`, if you add a dot before `run` you'll get:

`my_dir./run`

Answer (score 0):

```
exec(__DIR__ . './run uploads/testfile.txt',$output);

__DIR__ has no / at the end
```

So you will try to execute `/home/me/project./run`.

You could run `/home/me/project/./run` though for example. The dot . refers to the current directory.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by it has no / at the end?

Comment: if you directory name is `my_dir` then \__DIR__ = `my_dir`  and not `my_dir/`